# Java ArrayList remove dupes without sets

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having problems removing duplicates from an ArrayList. It's for an assignment for college. Here's the code I have already:

```
public int numberOfDiffWords() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<words.size()-1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<words.size(); j++) {
            if(words.get(i).equals(words.get(j))) {
                // do nothing
            }
            else  {
                list.add(words.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return list.size();
}
```

The problem is in the `numberOfDiffWords()` method. The populate list method is working correctly, as my instructor has given me a sample string (containing 4465 words) to analyse - printing `words.size()` gives the correct result.

I want to return the size of the new ArrayList with all duplicates removed.

`words` is an ArrayList class attribute.

UPDATE: I should have mentioned I'm only allowed to use dynamic indexed-based storage for this part of the assignment, which means no hash-based storage.

Comment: sorry, I thought I read somewhere on the site before to post it on an external site if it was too long...

Comment: If you are allowed to use the 'contains' method then this assignment is very straightforward.

Comment: doesn't work for me...gives me 9965880 different words.

Comment: For your own personal knowledge, this *could* be done in one line: `new HashSet<String>(words).size()`, and this would probably be the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: updated my post. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use anything hash-based.

Comment: @A.R.S. - The question title did say "without sets".

Comment: @TedHopp Oh right, didn't see that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is an assignment, I'm not going to write code. However, I'd suggest a different approach.

- iterate through the array as you are doing
- use the `subList()` method to construct a view of the array from the start up to but not including the current element
- use `contains()` to test whether the current element is in the sublist constructed in the previous step
- just count how many elements are found that are not contained in the prefix

My recommended approach should result in much simpler and easier-to-understand code. Note that all this is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution (as is yours, if you were to get it right).

Another approach, if modifying the array is allowed by the assignment, is to sort the array. Then equal elements will be adjacent and it is easy to count how many are unique. This is an O(n log(n)) approach. (You can also just make a copy of the array, which won't change the assymptotic complexity, but will slow down the solution.)

You won't get better than that without using a hashing function of some kind (`HashSet` or `HashMap`).

Comment: Upvoting as this is close enough for the OP, but there *is* an (nlogn) solution that doesn't use hashing.

Comment: @Perception - I believe that I mentioned that. I don't know all the constraints that apply in OP's assignment.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get the 'copy-array' part of your solution, but you did mention nlogn. Upvoted regardless!

Comment: @Perception - I didn't put that first because I don't know all the constraints that apply in OP's assignment. The first approach is the only one that uses _only_ indexing into arrays (and `subList`, which I would hope counts as indexing). Thanks for the upvote, by the way!

Comment: Ted, thanks for the advice. I'm not sure how to properly use the `subList()` method to be honest. Is it something like (inside the second loop) `if(words.subList(0, j-1).contains(words.get(j))) // add to new list` ?

Comment: @Kieran - Almost. It should be `subList(0, j)` since `subList` excludes the last index. However, you don't need a second list; you just need to count how many element you _would have added_ if you were building a list of unique elements. Since you don't actually need that second list, just keep a running count.

Comment: so this is the new code:
`int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<words.size()-1; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<words.size(); j++) {
                if(words.subList(0, j).contains(words.get(j))) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;`
It just hangs for me...

Comment: @Kieran - You only need one loop: `int count = 0; for (int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) { if (!words.subList(0, i).contains(words.get(i))) { count++; } } return count;`. (Note that I reversed the logic of the `if`--you want to increment `count` when the word is _not_ present in the prefix list.) I'm not sure why your code is hanging--it won't get the right answer, but it doesn't look like it should hang.

Comment: @TedHopp, thanks for the reply. It's not hanging now, but it's still not giving the correct answer. It's giving me 4655 - the same as the number of words in the string. The number of different words should be 779.

Comment: @Kieran - I just tested my code and it works fine for me. (It's a smaller list than yours, but it had plenty of duplicates and gave the right result.) Are you perhaps not using the code I posted? Or perhaps there is an error elsewhere?

Comment: @TedHopp, can I send you my Netbeans project to take a look. I can't see where I have a problem with any of my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20483/discussion-between-kieran-and-ted-hopp)

Answer (score 2):

If you intend on using that method, then this is your problem: Modify the if-then-else such that it does not add the words inside the second loop. Verify in the inner loop whether there are duplicates, with a boolean variable, and if there is no duplicate, add the word to your list after the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running loop for whole length you should check duplicate by calling **contains()** method on the arraylist.

```
  word.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).contains(arg);
```

this way your code will be very succinct.

Comment: Much better (and pretty much what I outlined. :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you use a nested for loop structure to iterate through, remove dupes of each element, and then add the remaining elements to a new array, you can return a smaller array. I'm not sure if this is the fastest way to do it, but it works.

```
// Delete all dupes
for ( i=0; i<words.length; i++ ) {
  String word = words[i];
  for ( j=(i+1); j<words.length; j++) {
     if (words[j] == words[i]) {
        words[j] = null;
     }
  }
}

// Count the array w/o nulls
int countEl = 0;
for (i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  if (words[i] != null) {
     countEl++;
  }
}

// Make a new array
String[] newArray = new String[countEl];

for (i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  if (words[i] != null) {
    countEl.push(words[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't really want to use == to check equality of strings.

Comment: Since when can you call a method (like `push()`) for an `int`? `countE1.push(words[i]);` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make it more simple, try this

```
final ArrayList duplicateWords = new ArrayList() ;
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Object e) {
        if( !contains(e) ) {
        return super.add(e);
        } else {
            duplicateWords.add(e);
            return false ;
        }
    }
};
System.out.println("Unique words : " + words.size());
System.out.println("Duplicate words : " + duplicateWords.size());
```

This is an alternate answer.